# Sorting datagridview with Swedish Alphabet - Å Ä Ö

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to sort my datagridview correctly when cells contain the (Swedish) letters Å, Ä and Ö.

Currently it sorts Å as an A and Ö as an O.

They should appear after Z.

My CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ("sv-SE") and I'm using the default sorting.

Thanks very much

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As read [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/111813-unicode-sorting) :

Set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to appropriate culture.

If your table is part of a dataset then you might set DataSet.Locale to a
desired CultureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

The default sort method provided by DatagridView does the trick.

```
public void test()
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    dataGridView.Columns.Add("Col1", "Col1");
    dataGridView.Columns.Add("Col2", "Col2");
    dataGridView.Columns.Add("Col3", "Col3");

    dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { 'Á', 2, 3 });
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { 'Ä', 2, 3 });
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { 'A', 2, 3 });
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { 'Ö', 2, 3 });
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { 'O', 2, 3 });
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { 'Z', 2, 3 });

    dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(row.Cells[column.Name].Value);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
A 3 5 
O 2 1 
Z 2 3 
Á 2 3 
Ä 1 2 
Ö 5 9
```